# ¿Qué significa 'estallar' en "Frente a frente" de Enrique Bunburry?

Tags: verbos, significado, letras-de-canciones, significado-en-contexto

> Queda, qué poco queda
> De nuestro amor apenas queda nada
> Apenas ni palabras
> Quedan
> Queda solo el silencio
> Que hace [estallar](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/estallar) la noche fría y larga
> La noche que no acaba
> Solo eso queda

Quería agregar a [wiktionary](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/estallar) este fragmento de [la famosa canción](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2eIy648WfJQ) como el ejemplo del uso del verbo [estallar](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/estallar).

Comment: I am reminded of the poetic "dawn came up like thunder" (Kipling) which has a similar ring to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hablamos de un texto lírico sujeto a interpretación totalmente subjetiva, donde el autor emplea el [oxímoron](https://dle.rae.es/ox%C3%ADmoron) y la [metáfora](https://www.lexico.com/es/definicion/metafora) para expresar sus sentimientos.

En mi opinión el significado que se aplica a estallar [de entre los que citas](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/estallar) es

> 3. Comenzar un suceso de modo violento e inesperado.

Al relacionar el silencio con un estallido es cuando encontramos el ejemplo clásico de oxímoron, un silencio ensordecedor (o atronador como indica @mdewey y recoge el DLE). Al percibir ese silencio, da comienzo de forma súbita y abrupta la noche, como metáfora de un periodo oscuro anímicamente hablando.
El silencio hace que el autor sea consciente de la ausencia y le sobreviene un fuerte dolor emocional al darse cuenta de lo que ha perdido y de lo importante que era para él.

Como nota curiosa, podemos encontrar la asociación entre silencio y oscuridad desde los primeros éxitos escritos por Búnbury. Así lo atestigua la letra de [Héroe de Leyenda](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7top5v_-3dY)

> Siempre en la **oscuridad**
>  La voz no tiene sentido
>  El **silencio** lo es todo
> Héroe en su propio olvido